# MediaPlayer is null when external ringtone sound is used

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that should alarm with specific ringtone which can be selected with default ringtone picker.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, getString(R.string.setup_ringtone));
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, SharedPrefUtil.getRingtone() != null ? Uri.parse(SharedPrefUtil.getRingtone()) : null);
this.startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_RINGTONE);
```

After it is selected I save its path to Shared Preferences in onActivityResult

```
Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
if (uri != null) {
    SharedPrefUtil.setRingtone(uri.toString());
}
```

And use it in MediaPlayer later like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ContextProvider.getAppContext(), Uri.parse(SharedPrefUtil.getRingtone()));          
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.start();
```

In the case with default device ringtones it works fine.

But if I set some song as phone ringtone it appears in the ringtone picker. And when I select it MediaPlayer is always null on its initialization. 
However, **Uri.parse(SharedPrefUtil.getRingtone())** returns me normal value - **content://media/external/audio/media/366**. The same as for other default ringtones, just with another id.

Also, it is recognized when I set it as selected for the ringtone picker here

```
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, SharedPrefUtil.getRingtone() != null ? Uri.parse(SharedPrefUtil.getRingtone()) : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom ringtone that is stored on the external storage, the RingtoneManager is not able to open it unless your app has the permission to access the external storage.

add missing permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```